How can I lazily traverse a directory in lisp?
I've been working on processing a large amount of files with lisp and encountering an issue listing directory contents when there are millions of files in a directory.
I found cl-fad and the (list-directory "./data") function, but this loads the entire list of files into memory which exhausts the heap and fails. Found similar behavior using the uiop functions such as (uiop:directory-files "./data")
Are there any existing options for traversing each file in the directory without loading all the filenames into memory?

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/files.html#listing-files-and-directories mentions cl-fad:walk-directory, but it might use list-directory internally. I don't think CL has a built-in equivalent to opendir/readdir, you might need to use a FFI to write your own.

yeah, walk directory basically does list-directory and calls a function on each item, so it's the same

Putting millions of files in a single directory is often a design problem to begin with. Many things will have trouble with it, e.g. ls tries to sort the directory by default.

And the problem with using readdir() through FFI is that the layout and contents of a struct dirent vary from OS to OS. Writing a portable version becomes a huge pain. Easier if you only care about a particular system.

LispWorks has a function hcl:fast-directory-files : https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw80/lw/lw-hcl-74.htm#LWUGRM)fast-directory-files

Allegro CL has a function map-over-directory : https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/operators/excl/map-over-directory.htm

osicat (https://osicat.common-lisp.dev/) has opendir/readdir/closedir with readdir returning 3 values, as well as "with-directory-iterator"
